# Google Sheets IMPORTXML XPath Query

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to use the IMPORTXML function in Google sheets to grab the time stamp on this page - https://www.dealsandreviews.co.uk/best-bookshelf-speakers-ranked.

I have used developer tools in chrome to highlight the time stamp and copy the xpath. My formula looks like this:

`=importxml(a1, (//*[@id="cb-featured-image"]/div[1]/div/span/time))`

However there is formula parse error. Could someone help educate me with the correct formula?

Thanks!

Comment: Text values should be enclosed between `"` an inner `"` be replaced by `'`.

Answer (score 1):

Text values should be enclosed between `"`. However, An inner `"` should  be replaced by `'`.

Try

```
 =importxml(a1, "(//*[@id='cb-featured-image']/div[1]/div/span/time)")
```

Note: `IMPORTXML` only sees the source code while Google Chrome shows the code of the displayed page that could not be the same due to JavaScript or by changes made by the browser engine, so the `xPath` returned by Google Chrome could be seen by `IMPORTXML`.